# select query in mysql always return empty result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I run this simple query  with PHP and also phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT * FROM `rdm_order` WHERE `aff_result` != "xyc"
```

I checked. table,column and rows are exist.

but the query return me empty result.

`aff_result` is this format: `VARCHAR(10) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci`

It seems all thing is correct. what is wrong?

[image: Sample data]

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log - (Ubuntu)
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2g
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev 
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 7.0.16
```

Comment: All `aff_result` values are `xyc` or `NULL`.

Comment: in tables, is NULL

Comment: @HoneyBadger I did it. same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the values are `NULL`.  `NULL` cannot be captured by an `=` or `!=` comparison.  Use the following instead:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     `rdm_order` 
WHERE    `aff_result` != 'xyc'
OR       `aff_result` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `NULL`-safe comparison operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM `rdm_order`
WHERE not `aff_result` <=> 'xyc';
```

The ANSI standard operator is `is distinct from`.

Comment: Not works. the query works for text and int type. but not for varchar.

Comment: This doesn't work for `varchar()`?  That is really strange.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not have any good reason to set default value of `aff_result` as NULL, you can modify your `aff_result` column and set default value as '' (blank string) using mysql alter command and your query will return the expected result set.
As explained by @Siyual, NULL cannot be captured by an = or != comparison.
And using OR operator in where clause is not index friendly.

Comment: If you can share the reason to downvote, i will really appreciate that.